# How to route a request with extension to a specific Controller's action in CakePHP 2.2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.0 and I need to create one route that get this kind of page:

```
http://www.example.com/users/mypage.php
```

Following the cakephp documentation, I have found this page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

where I read that I must to use:

```
Router::parseExtensions('php');
```

I have added this line in my routes.php file (above the routes), and than I added this route:

```
Router::connect('/users/mypage.php', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'mypage'));
```

So, inside UsersController I added this action.

Unfortunately, Only the requests sent to  `www.example.com/users/mypage` work good(the mypage action is called), If I try `www.example.com/users/mypage.php` I get a **404 not found error**.

I really do not understand the reason, As the documentation says:

> This will tell the router to remove any matching file extensions, and
>   then parse what remains.

So, that's exactly what I need, I have to interpret (**only for this action**) that the **mypage** action is called when the user digits /users/mypage.php (with extension).

I did not added anything else. AppController is as default, and my UsersController only has the mypage() method.

I do not know if NGINX is the problem, I write the configuration of the domain below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /home/users/example.com/www/app/webroot/;

        access_log /home/users/example.com/log/access.log;
        error_log /home/users/example.com/log/error.log;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

I think the question is clear, How to route the request to a specific Controller's action if the request has the extension ?

I need:

```
www.example.com/users/mypage.php ==> to UsersController mypage()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you either use parseExtensions() or add ".php" to the url template with connect(). You cannot use both at the same time. Whatever you choose, I suggest an experiment. Try using any other extensions such as "php5" and see that it works just fine. So obviously your problem is your nginx configuration:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Those lines are telling nginx to parse anything in the url that ends in .php as a hard file in your file system. This is not very easy to overcome. You can use try_files in that directive having a fallback to another script, which is tricky, or you could simply just use another extension for your url :)

I hope this gives you a good hint of what you have to do.

Comment: thank you, however, I tried adding .php to the connect (and remove parseExtensions()) and do the viceversa, I always get 404 not found, so as you told me, NGINX should be the problem... what do you advice? I repeat try_files in that box?

Answer (score 0):

this is my nginx.conf for cakephp 2.2.1:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/errordebug.log debug;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/  @cakephp;
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }
    location @cakephp {
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$request_uri;   #&$args;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }

    location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
       access_log off;
       expires 1d;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```